# The best way to manage private key in a shared computer

Tags: git, security, private-key

I'd like to know a secure way to manage a private key in a shared computer.
The private key is used for GitHub authentication to pull/push/clone/ to "git://...". However, the PC is shared with other people.  Some of them can be root users, so they can read my private key. If they read it, they will have an access privilege to my repository. In addition, my GitHub password is too long to remember. It is generated by a password management application, so I don't remember it. Because of this, I can not type password by using a Git URL "https://...".

What I want to do is to use `git` in a shared PC in a secure way. 
Could you give me some suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the git console you can add a passphrase to your key while generating it.

Basicly execute `ssh-keygen` and it will ask you where to place the key and what passphrase you want.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/private/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [PASSPHRASE]
Enter same passphrase again: [PASSPHRASE]
Your identification has been saved in /home/private/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/private/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:SPGTnzBrBfGCktlJm3iNRepVRS4XymcCrs3zq/g4g2g your_email@example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|      o.*..o+    |
|     * & B o .   |
|    = @ @ B =    |
|     = * O B     |
|      + S o      |
|       . o       |
|   . .    .      |
|  E . oo   .     |
| .    o+o..      |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

**Here is an indepth tutorial by github:**

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

*Also all modern git managers provide a generator with passphrase.*

Comment: Hi, Marvin! Thank you very much for your very quick answer. I actually tried to use a passphrase and understood how it works. This is exactly what I want. Thank you very much for your help. I gave you an upvote, but unfortunately, I could not because of less reputation...

Comment: Passphrase protects nothing as root can install a keylogger. In short: if you don't trust admins don't use their computer systems. You cannot protect yourself from a malicious root.

Comment: @Thomas you need to enter the password on the shared one to use the ssh key